# why React Renders Twice even if the react strict mode is off

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

There is no error in my code don't know why React renders this component twice.

Here is the Image for my problem.

[image: image1]

Index.js Page :

```
import LandingPage from '../components/Home/LandingPage.jsx'
import Layout from './../components/Layout';

export default function Home() {
  return (    
    <Layout section={<LandingPage/>}></Layout>
      
    )
}
```

My Layout.js Page

```
import React from 'react'
import Head from 'next/head'
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar';
import Footer from '../components/Footer';

export default function Layout({ section, children, title,description }) {
  return (
      <>
          <Head>
          <title>{ title? title   :'create next app' }</title>
                <meta name="description" content={description} />
                <link rel="icon" href="https://cdn.logo.com/hotlink-ok/logo-social.png" />
             </Head>
          <div className=' flex min-h-screen flex-col justify-between bg-gray-50'>
              <header className='sticky top-0 z-50 bg-white'>              
                <nav >
                   <Navbar/>
                </nav>
        </header>   
        <section>
          {section}
        </section>
              <main className='container mx-auto  px-4'>
                  {children}                  
              </main>
              <footer>
                 <Footer/>
              </footer>
             
          </div>
      
      </>
  )
}
```

LandingPage.jsx

```
import React from 'react'

export default function LandingPage() {
  return (<><div className='Image-landing-page'>
        <h1 className="  text-xl  font-bold   sm:mt-0   leading-8 md:font-extrabold tracking-tight text-white sm:text-3xl  text-center  "> Hello world </h1>
      </div></>
```

css:

```
.Image-landing-page{
    background-image: url('https://i.pinimg.com/564x/bd/ac/32/bdac327b05ddaa05216dfa08c9e734c3.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-top:10%;
    margin:0!important;
    padding-bottom:30%;
    font-size: 22px;
}
```

I also Tried turning off React strict mode in  next.config.js as I am using Next js for my project this problem still exists.

Comment: Can you share what is ` {children}`  in your case because in your example you have nothing passed as children? It seems like you have repeatation of the code in your footer too. Can you share  If you have nothing passed a chidlren use this syntax
```
<Layout section={<LandingPage/>} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not implement it it properly just  :

change **index.js** file like this :

```
import LandingPage from '../components/Home/LandingPage.jsx'
import Layout from './../components/Layout';

export default function Home() {
  return (    
    <Layout>
           <LandingPage/>
    </Layout>
      
    )
}
```

and in the **Layout.js** like this  :

```
import React from 'react'
import Head from 'next/head'
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar';
import Footer from '../components/Footer';

export default function Layout({  children, title,description }) {
  return (
      <>
          <Head>
          <title>{ title? title   :'create next app' }</title>
                <meta name="description" content={description} />
                <link rel="icon" href="https://cdn.logo.com/hotlink-ok/logo-social.png" />
             </Head>
          <div className=' flex min-h-screen flex-col justify-between bg-gray-50'>
              <header className='sticky top-0 z-50 bg-white'>              
                <nav >
                   <Navbar/>
                </nav>
        </header>   
        
              <main className='container mx-auto  px-4'>
                  {children}                  
              </main>
              <footer>
                 <Footer/>
              </footer>
             
          </div>
      
      </>
  )
}
```